# Writing of pandas dataframe object to hdf5 via to_hdf is creating axis0, axis1, block0_items and block0_values, but why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, octave, hdf5

I have a csv file called test.csv with this content:

```
d,t,s,A,B
2021293,010000,.189545,-9.3868122,46.152637
2021293,010000,.388550,-9.3991013,46.22963
2021293,010000,.588547,-9.350419,46.189907
2021293,010000,.788544,-9.3768988,46.166893
2021293,010000,.988541,-9.3335829,46.134583
2021293,010001,.188538,-9.3287783,46.233955
2021293,010001,.388550,-9.3323059,46.203461
2021293,010001,.588547,-9.2911615,46.19883
2021293,010001,.788544,-9.322463,46.135742
2021293,010001,.988541,-9.2798738,46.236137
```

when I run the below code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv_filename = 'test.csv'
hdf_filename = 'test.h5'

csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_filename )
data     = pd.DataFrame.transpose(csv_data)

data.to_hdf(hdf_filename, key='foobar/data', mode='w', format='fixed')
```

and then inspect the hdf5 file in `octave` or `matlab`, via `load test.h5`, I see under `foobar.data`:

```
ans =

  1x1 struct array containing the fields:

    axis0
    axis1
    block0_items
    block0_values
```

but the staff who will be using the hdf5 file, expect the content of `foobar.data.block0_values` to be directly available in `foobar.data` and not have to traverse `foobar.data.block0_values`. How do I change that?

The content of `foobar.data.block0_values` is

```
foobar.data.block0_values
ans =

                 2021293                   10000                0.189545              -9.3868122               46.152637
                 2021293                   10000                 0.38855              -9.3991013                46.22963
                 2021293                   10000                0.588547               -9.350419               46.189907
                 2021293                   10000                0.788544      -9.376898799999999               46.166893
                 2021293                   10000                0.988541              -9.3335829               46.134583
                 2021293                   10001                0.188538              -9.3287783               46.233955
                 2021293                   10001                 0.38855              -9.3323059               46.203461
                 2021293                   10001                0.588547      -9.291161499999999                46.19883
                 2021293                   10001                0.788544      -9.322463000000001               46.135742
                 2021293                   10001                0.988541      -9.279873800000001               46.236137
```

while I expect that content to be directly in `foobar.data`.

Comment: Achieving this _within_ octave is extremely trivial (i.e. `foobar.data = foobar.data.block_values` ), but less so from within python. Is it a strict requirement that the data is packaged exactly as expected by the time it reaches the octave user? Also, why would you _not_ want the extra information about axes etc?

Comment: It is a requirement that the data be packaged exactly as expected by the time it reaches the octave/matlab user. I don't have control over that requirement.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to re-format the hdf5 data in python manually, since your intention is to repackage it in a non-standard format. For context, what you're trying to do is a bit like wanting to send the data-bits of a png image file 'only', instead of the whole image file which also includes useful headers and can be read by standard facilities. If you're not restricted to hd5 specifically, the only workaround I can think which keeps your user's api the same, is to save the data as .mat files rather than .h5 files (i.e. using the scipy.io.savemat module) in your preferred format.

Answer (score 1):

HDF5 is a container, and not a fixed format. Each software package is free to implement the HDF5 schema as they desire. As a consequence, you have to understand the HDF5 schema required by each package. From my limited experience with Pandas, HDF5 data is always written with the schema you see (datasets named: `axis0, axis1, block0_items, block0_values` and sometimes `block1_items, block1_values`). If the file needs to work in `matlab` and/or `octave`, you need to determine the schema they expect when reading HDF5 data.

HDF5 has 2 basic dataset types:

1. *Homogeneous* datasets where all values have the same type: all `ints` or `floats` or `strings`. That looks like the approach used by Pandas.
2. *Heterogeneous* datasets with values saved in columns of different types.

The "challenge" with your data is the mix of integers and floats. That implies 2 possible approaches with your HDF5 schema:

1. Create *homogeneous* datasets with `ints` in dataset1 and `floats` in dataset2 (plus some info to reassemble). That's the Pandas approach.
2. Create *heterogeneous* datasets. The result 'looks' like a Pandas dataframe in
   **HDFView**. You can do this with the `PyTables` or the `h5py` packages. The
   key is creating a NumPy recarray from the dataframe dtypes, then loading the dataframe values into the recarray. Based on previous HDF5 experience I am "pretty sure" matlab can read this format as you expect.

This example shows how to create a heterogeneous dataset with both packages. The only real difference is function call to create the dataset.  (Note: PyTables is used by Pandas to access HDF5, so may already be installed with Pandas -- but you will have to verify.)

Add the following lines to your example to see how it works:

```
# extract column names and dtypes to create the recarray dtype
arr_dt = []   
for col in csv_data.columns:
    arr_dt.append( (col, csv_data[col].dtype) )   
nrows = csv_data.values.shape[0]    
# create an empty recarray based on Pandas dataframe row count and dtype
arr = np.empty( (nrows,), dtype=arr_dt )

# load dataframe column values into the recarray fields
for col in csv_data.columns:
    arr[col] = csv_data[col].values
    
print(arr)   

# use PyTables to write recarray to h5 file
import tables as tb
with tb.File(hdf_filename, mode='a')  as h5f:
    h5f.create_table('/tb','csv_data',obj=arr,createparents=True)
    
# use h5py to write recarray to h5 file
import h5py
with h5py.File(hdf_filename, mode='a')  as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset('h5py/csv_data',data=arr)
```